# newcommand - no linebreak

Tags: underline

I am trying to write a new command that will underline the text from the first argument and add the red comment of the second argument. I think I've got this mostly, but the result does not add the appropriate break lines, and I don't understand why. Where is the problem?

Command:
`\newcommand\comment[2]{\underline{#1}\textcolor{red}{\emph{\textbf{comment}: #2}}}`

Code:

```
\comment{Only $1\%$ of the mass is comprised of the interstellar medium. The rest is in the form of interstellar gas}{interstellar medium means the interstellar gas.},
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You can consider the `soul` package.

Comment: `\underline` is a box like `\mbox` and prevents line breaks

Comment: Thank you! Using `soul` package and `\ul` instead of `\underline` solved that :)

Comment: [`ulem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) does also support underlining with line breaks. By default it additionally replaces emphasizing by underlining. You can load it with `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` to prevent this.